# state data is updating without set state method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i am trying to use the state hook in my react native app. But without calling the set state method, my state value is updating

```js
export default function Interface(){
    const [requireddata,setrequireddata]= useState({vehiclesfulldata:[]});
    const [requireddataflag,setrequireddataflag]=useState(true);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const interfacedata= async function fetchinterfacedata() {
            const resultdata=  await Fetchdata(postdata).then(async(response) => {
                let responsedata=JSON.parse(response);
                return responsedata
            })

            setrequireddata({...requireddata, vehiclesfulldata:JSON.parse(resultdata.fullvehicledata)});

        }
        interfacedata();
       
    },[requireddataflag])


    const fleetsearchdata=(searchdata)=>{ 
        let fleetdetails=requireddata.vehiclesfulldata;
        if(searchdata!=""){
            searchdata=searchdata.toLowerCase();
            fleetdetails.forEach((g)=> {
                g.fleets.forEach((s)=> {
                    s.fleets = s.fleets.filter(f => f.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchdata) > -1);
                })
            })

        }
        console.log(fleetdetails);
        console.log(requireddata.vehiclesfulldata);
        // console.log(fleetdetails); 
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={[Interfacestyle.fleetsearchview]}> 
                <Input
                    placeholder='Search Fleet' 
                    onChangeText={(value)=>{fleetsearchdata(value)}}
                    inputContainerStyle={Interfacestyle.inputcontainerfleetsearch}  
                    containerStyle={Interfacestyle.inputfleetsearch} 
                    style={Interfacestyle.fleetsearch}  
                    rightIcon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'search' ,color:'#C9C9C9',size:17,solid:'true'}}
                    rightIconContainerStyle={Interfacestyle.fleetsearchIcon}
                />  
            </View> 
        </SafeAreaView>
    )

}
```

the above is my code. Initially i fetch the data by using fetch api, which get the result as

```
Array [
  Object {
    "GroupId": 1,
    "fleets": Array [
      Object {
        "GroupId": 1,
        "StationId": null,
        "fleets": Array [
          Object {
            "GroupId": 1,
            "StationId": null,
            "fleetId": 316,
            "name": "TM-175 PLATE-286398",
          },
        ],
        "name": "General",
      },
    ],
    "name": "TRUCK MIXER",
  },
]
```

while calling the function fleetsearchdata, the state value in requireddata is updating without calling
setrequireddata function.

kindly help me.

Comment: You are calling `setrequireddata` inside your `useEffect`. This code is running at least once on component mount. If I am mistaken or this doesn't help you, could you further explain your problem?

Comment: @NicolásLonghi  i called setrequireddata  inside the useeffect for setting the above mentioned array in to it. after that i calling fleetsearchdata function when the Input  text value change.inside the fleetsearchdata , is didnt call setrequireddata for setting the state after the filtering.Unfortunately ,the state is updating.(i use the console for printing the state value)

Comment: how is your variable `requireddataflag` being modified? your `useEffect` is listening on the change of that variable.

Comment: it is not modifying. So the use effect will only run when the component in loading. but requireddata is modifying inside   fleetsearchdata function. inside this function i wrote console.log for showing the requireddata.vehiclesfulldata. Its showing the modified data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your `fleetsearchdata` function you are assigning your state to a variable (`fleetdetails=requireddata.vehiclesfulldata`) and in this case any changes to `fleetdetails` will be made to the original variable since you are not making a copy but an assignment. So you would have to make a copy and then do the filtering. You can find more info here: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089

I would recommend using lodash's `_.cloneDeep`